# Using IPAddress.Address causes exception

Tags: c#

I have an old service in which I compare between 2 IP addresses (when the service is started) the following way:

```
if (IPAddress1.Address == IPAddress2.Address)
{
    ...
}
```

It always worked fine when installed and started on an 2003 server, but now when I tried to install it on an 2008 serve, I get the following exception:

> Service cannot be started. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : The
>   attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced
>   at System.Net.IPAddress.get_Address()

(The weird thing is that when tried to install and start it on a client 2008 server it worked).

What is the problem?

Comment: You're getting an IPv6 address. Check the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs) and don't ignore the warnings from the compiler that `Address` is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

According to the docs the [Address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.net.ipaddress.address.aspx) property is now obsolete - it's recommended you use [GetAddressBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes.aspx) instead.

For comparison though the docs recommend you use `Equals`

```
if (IPAddress1.Equals(IPAddress2))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Where is that recommended? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.net.ipaddress.address.aspx seems to suggest the use of `IPAddress.Equals`...

Comment: @Chris where it says `This property is obsolete. Use GetAddressBytes.`, however, I just realised that it does recommend `Equals` in the deprecation message (it most likely does the `byte[]` comparison internally).

Comment: Oh yeah. That is quite inconsistent. I suspect yours makes more sense because you might not be actually comparing addresses so Equals will not always make sense. Thanks for the clarification though.